Proving that a dynamical system has at least one limit cycle, and that if there are several, they all have the same period $T(a, b)$.
This is exercise $\bf 7.3.7$ of Nonlinear Dyanmics and Chaos by Strogatz.
$$
\mbox{Consider}\quad
\left\{\begin{array}{rcrcl}
\dot{x} & = & y & + & ax\left(1 - 2b - r^{2}\right)
\\
\dot{y} & = & -x & + & ay\left(1 - r^{2}\right)
\end{array}\right.
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are parameters $\left(\,0 < a \leq 1,\
0 \leq b < 1/2\,\right)$ and $r^{2} = x^{2} + y^{2}$.
(a) Rewrite the system in polar coordinates.
(b) Prove that there is at least one limit cycle, and that if there are several, they all have the same period $T(a, b)$.
(c) Prove that for $b=0$ there is only one limit cycle.
For (a) I have
\begin{align}
        r\dot{r} &= x\dot{x} + y\dot{y}\\
        &= x\left(y+a x\left(1-2 b-r^2\right)\right) + y\left(-x+a y\left(1-r^2\right)\right)\\
        &= xy + ax^2 - 2abx^2 - ax^2r^2 - xy+ ay^2 - ay^2r^2\\
        &= ar^2 - 2abx^2 - ar^4\\
        \implies \dot{r} &= ar - 2abr\cos^2\theta - ar^3
    \end{align}
\begin{align}
\dot{\theta} &= \frac{x\dot{y} - y\dot{x}}{r^2}\\
&= \frac{x\left(-x+a y\left(1-r^2\right)\right) - y\left( y+a x\left(1-2 b-r^2\right))\right)}{r^2}\\
&= \frac{-x^2 + axy - axyr^2 - y^2 - axy + 2abxy + axy r^2}{r^2}\\
&= -1 + 2ab \cos \theta \sin \theta
\end{align}
For (b) I decided to find the annulus where $\dot{r} < 0$ on the outer boundary and $\dot{r} > 0$ on the inner boundary. I have the bounds for $\dot{r}$
$$-ar^3 \dot{r}\leq a(2r - r^3)$$
The lower bound is never positive though. The upper bound is negative when $r > \sqrt{2}$ so I can use that as my outer region.
For (c) I'm not sure how to approach this part.

For $b=0$, $\dot{r}= ar - ar^3$ has the explicit solution
$$ r(t)=\frac{e^{a t}}{\sqrt{e^{2 a t}+C}}$$
with $C>0$. Note
$$ \lim_{t\to\infty}r(t)=1$$
which gives the uniqueness of the limit cycle.
